# Change address of a bincopy segment

Tags: python-3.x

What is the easiest method to change the start address of a bincopy segment?

For example, I have the code:

```
import bincopy
f = bincopy.BinFile("sample.hex")
print( f.segments )
```

which gives:

```
Segment(address=0, data=bytearray(b'\xaa\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\xaa'))
Segment(address=96, data=bytearray(b'\xdd\x00\x00\x00\x22\x00\x00\xdd'))
Segment(address=160, data=bytearray(b'\xee\x00\x00\x00\x33\x00\x00\xee'))
```

How to change the start address of the second segment from 96 to 60, for example?

Answer (score 0):

What I have found so far:

```
bindata = f.as_binary(minimum_address=MY_START_ADDRESS, maximum_address=MY_END_ADDRESS)
f.add_binary(bindata, address=MY_DEST_ADDRESS, overwrite=False)
```

However, this solution has the disadvantage that the new datarange is handled by bincopy as a single segment without splitting it into multiple segments if there are empty spaces in between.

Therefore, another solution is to loop over the segments in the relevant range and move the one by one:

```
g = bincopy.BinFile()

for seg in f.segments:
    g.add_binary( seg.data, address= seg.address + offset, overwrite=False)
```